# Ajax function is only working in one div not other

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

My code works fine in this way. There are multiple `div`s and `$chat_id` is unique for each `div`, so they look like:

```
<div id=chatbox_1>...
<div id=chatbox_2>...
...etc.
```

**index.php:**

```
<div id="chatbox_<?php echo $chat_id; ?>" >
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#chatbox_<?=$chat_id?>').load('chat.php?id=<?=$chat_id?>')
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

**chat.php:**

```
<?php 
include 'db.php';

if (isset($_GET['id'])){
    $c_id = $_GET['id'];
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM `chat` where `chat_id`='$c_id'";
$run = $con->query($query);
while($row = $run->fetch_array()){ ?>

<div id="chat_data">
    <span style="color:brown;"><?php echo $row['msg']; ?></span>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

The problem is when I am trying this ajax it is only working for one `div`. Other `div`s are not loading the `chat.php`

```
<div id="chatbox_<?php echo $chat_id; ?>" >
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    function ajax(){
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('chatbox_<?=$chat_id?>').innerHTML = req.responseText;
            } 
        }
        req.open('GET','chat.php?id=<?=$chat_id?>',true); 
        req.send();
    }

    setInterval(function(){ajax()},1000);
    </script>
</div>
```

`.load` is working perfectly but this ajax function is working for only one `div`. The rest are empty. What should I change here, or should I use other method?

Comment: It will work for one `id` as per above code, if you want to load for each chat_ids, you should use `class` rather than `id` and loop through each `class` using `.each` function

Answer (score 1):

You should only have one general JavaScript function and it should not be inside the `div` it's acting on. I am not very good at vanilla javascript, but it would be something like this:

```
<!-- You just load the id into the ajax function -->
<div id="chatbox_<?php echo $chat_id ?>" onload="setInterval(function(){ajax('<?php echo $chat_id ?>')},1000);"></div>

<!-- You only have one function and it is all javascript-based -->
<script type="text/javascript" >
function ajax(id)
    {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(req.readyState == 4 && req.status == 200){
                document.getElementById('chatbox_'+id).innerHTML = req.responseText;
            } 
        }
        req.open('GET','chat.php?id='+id,true); 
        req.send();
    }
</script>
```

Your PHP should be adjusted to not have such an SQL and XSS vulnerability:

```
<?php 
include('db.php');
# Check if the GET value is numeric (presuming it is supposed to be)
if(isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])){
    $c_id = $_GET['id'];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `chat` where `chat_id`='{$c_id}'";
    $run = $con->query($query);
    while($row = $run->fetch_array()){ ?>
<div id="chat_data">
    <!-- You need to sanitize your output or you will have people taking advantage
    of javascript hackery -->
    <span style="color:brown;"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['msg'],ENT_QUOTES) ?></span>
</div>
<?php }
}
```